# ElasticSearch add more nodes to cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

i have Elasticsearch cluster which contains 3 nodes

```
- node-1 (master-eligible and data node)
- node-2 (master-eligible and data node) 
- node-3 (data node)
```

and in the elasticsearch.yml config i have following line

```
discovery.seed_hosts: ["node-1", "node-2", "node-3"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-1"]
```

but i want to add 2 nodes in this cluster

```
- node-4 (will be data only node)
- node-5 (will be only master node)
```

so should i change the cluster.initial.master_nodes parameter and add the node-5, or not? in docs i see You should not use this setting when restarting a cluster or adding a new node to an existing cluster. so this setting should be untouched? and in config on new nodes i should leave this parameter as on "old nodes?"